# Is the placement of Jupiter (Guru) in the sixth house good or bad?

Tags: astrology, brihaspati

Suppose, Jupiter or Brihaspati Graha is placed in the 6th house from the ascendant in some chart.

Is this placement considered good for bad for the native?

Some say it's not good but some others say that, since Guru is always a beneficial planet, it's good.

Comment: Jupiter and Sukra are natural benefics all right but that does not mean that they can't harm. For Gemini ascendant for eg Jupiter is a strong malefic. Also, to answer ur Q a lot of other factors are needed to be consulted.